# Is there a way to set {$SCOPEDENUMS ON} globally for the whole project?

Tags: delphi, enums, compiler-errors, delphi-xe6

I would like to enforce

```
{$SCOPEDENUMS ON}
```

on all of the units within a project.

Currently I add this to every unit immediately after the unit declaration:

```
unit unt_WotcSearch;
{$SCOPEDENUMS ON}
...
```

Is there a way I can set this globally (for example in the *.dpr file or project settings) so would not need to add {$SCOPEDENUMS ON} to hundreds of units?

Comment: It is common to use an include file for this

Comment: I can do so but yet I would have to add the {$I ScopedEnums.inc} to every unit - something I am trying to avoid.

Comment: As an aside, I have a {$I Defines.Inc} at the top of every unit. It just becomes automatic in there. You can probably even make a wizard to do it automatically, although I dont bother. There are several defines in there that I turn off and on as needed. Its a bit of a pain to set it up the first time, but then it becomes helpful.

Comment: When I have code that needs to appear in every unit I add a pre-build action that runs a script (Python, Ruby, Perl, grep, whatever) that checks that the required code does indeed appear. Then when you forget you get an error and cannot proceed until you fix the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no compiler parameter, and thus no project option, to control this directive. Which means that you have to set it locally in each unit.

Answer (score 3):

This directive only needs to be active at the point a particular enumeration is declared. Once an enumeration has been declared under this directive, any usage of it must be scoped with the name of the enumeration regardless of the current state of that directive. IOW, you cannot disable it and then use an enumeration element without qualifying those elements with the enumeration's name identifier.